# Foreign key choosable when create the model instance

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Amodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class Bmodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

now I have another model:

```
class Cmodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    f_model = models.ForeignKey(to='there I want to dynamic refers to Amodle or Bmodel when create the Cmodel instance')
```

I want the Cmodel's `f_model` is choosable when Create the Cmodel instance, whether this is possible?

Comment: give like `models.ForeignKey(table_name, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Answer (score 2):

This feature called generic relations. Here is the official documentation link [generic-relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)

Answer (score 0):

By definition of [foreign key](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) you can not assign foreign key to one field with choices of model

> A FOREIGN KEY is a key used to link two tables together.
>
> A FOREIGN KEY is a field (or collection of fields) in one table that refers to the PRIMARY KEY in another table.

Instead you can proceed to create two fields as below:

```
class Cmodel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    f_a_model = models.ForeignKey(Amodel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    f_b_model = models.ForeignKey(Bmodel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This way you can create two fields and you can keep it as null.
So If you wish to proceed for `Cmodel` instance with foreign key of a model you can add it to field `f_a_model` and keep `f_b_model` null and vice versa

You may follow example of using generic-relations from [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/13/how-to-use-generic-relations.html) link and the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/).

When you use generic relations you need to write your own custom field and method for serializer or form or anywhere you wish to user it.

Comment: but however the model is more than `Amodel` and `Bmodel`?

Comment: @244boy could you explain a bit what you just asked "but however the model is more than Amodel and Bmodel?"

Comment: you need to create foreign key per model and if you don't want to do that you can go for generic foreign key